# Sharepoint 2013 extend ContentBySearchWebpart

Tags: sharepoint

> My Query in Short :

I extended ContentBySearchWebpart, so that i could create my custom Query for Search. I modified the DataProviderJSON Property and added my custom QueryTemplate in it. But the  Webpart renders with default results

> What i am trying to do :

1. I created a catalog site collection and other publishing site collection
2. Created a List in catalog site, enabled it as catalog, made connection of this catalog in publishing site.
3. Added CSWP in publishing site Whose Result Source is the above catalog connection.
4. Now i want to customize my query

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. We are required to set some of the base properties in constructor of our extended webpart. Below is a code sample :

```
            string dataProviderJson = "{{'Properties':{{'TryCache':true,'Scope':'{0}','HHTitle_WB_Marker1':50,'HHTitle_WB_Marker2':60,'UpdateLinksForCatalogItems':true,'EnableStacking':true,'searchTerms':'','Tag':''}},'QueryGroupName':'Default','SourceID':'8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89','SourceName':'Local SharePoint Results (System)','SourceLevel':'Ssa','CollapseSpecification':'','QueryTemplate':'{{searchTerms?}} (contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) SPSiteUrl:{1} ListId:3d001e7a-d856-428b-9785-edf7ec4f4876 {{?owstaxidMetadataRegion:{{Tag}}}}  owstaxIdMetadataRegion:{2}','FallbackSort':[{{'p':'Rank','d':0}}],'RankRules':[],'AsynchronousResultRetrieval':false,'SendContentBeforeQuery':true,'BatchClientQuery':true,'FallbackLanguage':-1,'FallbackRankingModelID':'8f6fd0bc-06f9-43cf-bbab-08c377e083f4','EnableStemming':true,'EnablePhonetic':false,'EnableNicknames':false,'EnableInterleaving':true,'EnableQueryRules':true,'EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty':false,'HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit':-1,'IgnoreContextualScope':false,'ScopeResultsToCurrentSite':false,'TrimDuplicates':true,'ClientType':'ContentSearchRegular','UpdateAjaxNavigate':true,'SummaryLength':180,'DesiredSnippetLength':90,'PersonalizedQuery':false,'FallbackRefinementFilters':null,'IgnoreStaleServerQuery':false,'RenderTemplateId':'DefaultDataProvider','AlternateErrorMessage':null,'Title':''}}";
            string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site != null ? SPContext.Current.Site.Url.Trim() : "";
            base.ResultsPerPage = 3;
            base.BypassResultTypes = true;
            base.AlwaysRenderOnServer = false;
            dataProviderJson = String.Format(dataProviderJson, siteUrl, siteUrl + "/sites/Catalog", "en");
            base.DataProviderJSON = dataProviderJson;
            base.ItemTemplateId = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Banner.js";
            base.GroupTemplateId = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Group_Content.js";
            base.SelectedPropertiesJson = "['PublishingImage','PictureURL','PictureThumbnailURL','Path','Title','Description','SecondaryFileExtension','ContentTypeId']";
            base.HitHighlightedPropertiesJson = "['Title','Path','Author','SectionNames','SiteDescription']";
            base.QueryGroupName = "Default";
            base.RenderTemplateId = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Control_Banner.js";
            base.StatesJson = "{}";
            base.Title = "Banner Search WebPart";
            base.Description = "Banner Search WebPart";
            base.AllowMinimize = true;
            AllowConnect = true;
            AllowEdit = true;
            AllowHide = true;
            base.ZoneID = "ImportedPartZone";
```